# Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid with v3 js sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to upgrade my aws sdk v2 to 3. My code works perfectly in 2 but getting warning so want to change. Here is the code I am trying..

```
 const scheduleParams = {
        Name: name,
       
        Description: `Event firing for ${data.name} on ${data.event_type}`,
        ScheduleExpression: `at(${formatted})`, // UTC time
        ScheduleExpressionTimezone: 'Asia/Dhaka',
        State: 'ENABLED',
        FlexibleTimeWindow: {
        Mode: 'OFF'
        }, 
        Target: 
        {
            RoleArn: '',
            Arn: '...:emailque',
            //Id: 'target-1',
            Input: JSON.stringify(data),
        },
     };


 await cloudWatchEvents.send(new PutRuleCommand(scheduleParams));
```

This code is giving me error : `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.`
I am trying to schedule a single run event and it is :`at(2023-03-23T01:55)`

This code worked with v2 `await scheduler.createSchedule(scheduleParams).promise()`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `@aws-sdk/client-scheduler` SDK with the `CreateScheduleCommand` command.

Example:

```js
import { CreateScheduleCommand, SchedulerClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-scheduler";

const schedulerClient = new SchedulerClient();

const scheduleCommand = new CreateScheduleCommand({
    Name: `test-${uuid()}`,
    Description: 'Test description',
    ScheduleExpression: `at(${date.toISOString().substring(0, 19)})`,
    ScheduleExpressionTimezone: 'Asia/Dhaka',
    Target: {
        "RoleArn": "",
        "Arn": "",
        "Input": ""
    },
    FlexibleTimeWindow: {
        Mode: 'OFF'
    },
})
const rule = await schedulerClient.send(scheduleCommand)
```